# Avoid copying when calling delegating constructors

Tags: c++

A class with delegating constructors

```
class A {
  A(SomeObject obj,   // requires a new copy of the object 
    int x,
    const string& y
  ) { // additional logic }
  A(SomeObject obj, const string& y)   
    :A(obj, 0, y) {}     // will obj be copied?
};
```

Target usage:

```
SomeObject obj;
A a1(obj, "first");
A a2(obj, "second");
```

The design is to construct `SomeObject` exactly once when construction of `A` is performed.
Will passing `obj` cause another `SomeObject` to be copy constructed when delegating to the other constructor?  If yes, how can I avoid it?

Comment: A shallow copy will be made, but passing it in by reference will solve that.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts, Shallow vs. deep very much depends on the `SomeObject` class.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Sure. The design is to copy SomeObject once when construction is called.

Comment: If you are using delegating constructors, why not create another constructor that accepts a reference to `SomeObject` that both your existing constructors delegate to?

Comment: Perhaps `SomeObject obj` -> `const SomeObject& obj`

Comment: @Candi Chiu Please, don't change your question when there are already comments and answers present. Mark an significant change in your question appropriately.

Comment: @cwschmidt I don't see a significant change.

Comment: @cwschmidt: That was my edit. I intended to clarify the question based on their comment.

Comment: @melpomene In the original question there was asked if there is any copy at all and now he asked if there is more than one copy. That's the difference I observed.

Comment: @cwschmidt The question has always been whether there will be an extra copy, since the first copy is put in place by design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `obj` is copied when delegating to the other constructor: this is not a permissible context for [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) or even for [automatic moving](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return).

The solution is to apply `std::move` to the argument in the member initializer list, or (for
a private target constructor) receive the object by non-`const` reference.  Either of these allows the (public) constructor to still receive its argument by value, as is the C++11 recommendation.

Comment: related: [The Nightmare of Move Semantics for Trivial Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o)

Answer (score -6):

No. It is not copied **from one constructor to the other**. You seem to be under the assumption that one constructor will initialize the object then pass it to the other, which isn't the case. See this quote from the [standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/special#class.base.init-6):

> A mem-initializer-list can delegate to another constructor of the constructor's class using any class-or-decltype that denotes the constructor's class itself. If a mem-initializer-id designates the constructor's class, it shall be the only mem-initializer; the constructor is a delegating constructor, and the constructor selected by the mem-initializer is the target constructor. The target constructor is selected by overload resolution. Once the target constructor returns, the body of the delegating constructor is executed. If a constructor delegates to itself directly or indirectly, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

This minimal example shows `Copied` only being printed once:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) {
        std::cout << "Copied";
    }
};

struct A {
    A(Foo f, int i) { }
    A(Foo f) : A(f, 0) { }
};

int main() {
    A a{Foo{}};
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your standards quote directly contradicts your answer.

Comment: There's nothing in that paragraph that says that parameters are not copied

Comment: @MooingDuck How can you copy an object that hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: @Fureeish That has nothing to do with delegating constructors.

Comment: @user9163035 Why do you think `obj` hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: Because he is concerned about the SomeObj parameter, not the A being constructed.

Comment: @user9163035 He is not asking if the instance of A is copied (which he is actually creating), but the instance of SomeObject that is passed among the constructors.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Can A be constructed by multiple constructors? If not, how can SomeObj be copied multiple times?

Comment: For the DV'ers, please see the edit and tell me how `SomeObj` is copied multiple times.

Comment: @user9163035  Where do you read "copied *multiple times*"? `obj` is copied at least once. That fact already shows that there is a copy. Even your example shows that, now...

Comment: changing your `A a{Foo{}};` to `Foo f; A a{f};` makes the copy constructor being called **two** times. Your example uses copy elision guaranteed since `C++17`. The real life example would most likely look like the above

Comment: @Fureeish Yes but it is not copied from delegating constructor to constructor **which is the point!** I could copy Foo as many times as I wanted, it's not the point.

Comment: @user9163035 Then where are the two calls to the copy constructor in Fureeish's example coming from?

Comment: @user9163035: You are observing copy elision in the _outer_ constructor call.

Comment: @user9163035 This crazy mess was dropped on me a while back: https://ideone.com/G9BiTY Shocked the hell out of me, but yeah, you can copy an uninitialized object.

Comment: lol @ add code example that shows the copy you claim doesn't exist

Comment: @user4581301, You can also make a null reference, but both are undefined behaviour, so the fact that you can loses a bit of significance. You can attempt to copy an uninitialized object, but you can't guarantee it will actually happen. As far as I'm aware, the only types for which `T t(t);` is legal are `unsigned char` and `std::byte`. (I'm not sure what the motivation behind that allowance is, though.)

Comment: @user4581301 that code example is more about copying an object that does not yet exist.  You can write code that (attempts to) copy uninitialized objects more simply, e.g. `T a; T b (a);` where T's default constructor performs no initialization

Comment: @chris I think the code with `T t(t);`, and user-provided copy-constructor, is correct so long as the copy-constructor does not mention any non-static data members (or base classes)

Comment: @M.M, Interesting point. [[dcl.init/12\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#12) does say that the object has an indeterminate value when storage is obtained. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `T t(t);` would obtain storage, giving `t` an indeterminate value, then proceed to copy that value when initializing `t`. However, this doesn't meet the exceptions to UB that are specfied later in that paragraph. This is pretty off-topic, so I created [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162382/t-tt-discussion) if you'd like to continue discussing it in there.

Comment: @chris I guess you refer to the section "If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behaviour is undefined except..." however no indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation in `T t(t)`. A reference is bound to the object with indeterminate value but that's fine

Comment: @M.M, I see your original logic now.

Comment: user9163035 : Because the delegated constructor may still be treated as a function call (from the delegating ctor that is), and the parameters for that call need to be constructed as normal rather than as some kind of substitute default parameter syntax. (which makes sense as the delegation may not even be visible to the code that defined the obect instance where default parameters do need to be visible).